# JQuery $.each returning same data set twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I'm building an Instagram mapping app and I'm trying to iterate through the returned JSON using $.each. I'm currently testing it by returning the coordinates of the picture into a `<div>`. It's working wonderfully, except the same data shows up twice. Here is the statement (the commented-out code is for putting it on the map):

```
$.each(photos.data, function (index, photo) {
    if (photo.location) {
        /* var photocoords = google.maps.LatLng(photo.location.latitude,location.longitude);
                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position: photocoords,
                                    map: map,
                                    title: 'Test'
                                            });//end new marker


                                    */
        photo = photo.location.latitude + ' , ' + photo.location.longitude + '<br>';

        $('#photos-wrap').append(photo);
    } //end if
    else {
        return true
    }
});
```

And the data it's returning:

```
38.9232268 , -77.0464289
35.046506242 , -90.025382579
35.189142533 , -101.987259233

38.9232268 , -77.0464289
35.046506242 , -90.025382579
35.189142533 , -101.987259233
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Do you have 2 photos with the same data? Can you show us what makes up photo?

Comment: you're probably running the `$.each` twice.

Comment: Can you post the actual JSON string or provide us with a public link to the JSON?

Comment: is there any enter between3rd and 4th line in the output as you have actually shown here?

Comment: you are overwriting `photo` variable

Comment: From `each()` `photo` comes as an `object` and inside the function you overwriting `photo` as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code to this one

```
    var new_photo = photo.location.latitude + ' , ' + photo.location.longitude + '<br>';
    $('#photos-wrap').append(new_photo);
```